(novice to compiler design) how does a recursive descent parser decide which nonterminal to parse if there are multiple
Let's say we have a grammar S -> A | F A -> id = exp F -> id ( arglist )
parse_A():
   match(id)
   match(EQ)
   parse_exp()

parse_F():
    match(id)
    match(LPAREN)
    parse_arglist()
    match(RPAREN)

I do not understand how the parser which starts in parse_S()knows if it should call parse_A()or parse_B(). Can someone tell me?
Many thanks!

I'm assuming that you want to write a predictive parser, i.e. one that doesn't need to do any backtracking to parse the language.
The languages parsed by predictive recursive descent parsers are called LL($k$) grammars, where the $k$ can be thought of as the number of lookahead token you need to parse the grammar predictively.
Your parser is an LL($1$) parser (you only look at one token in match), but as you noted this makes the choice of rule rule ambiguous, your grammar isn't LL($1$).
You can transform you grammar into an equivalent LL($1$) grammar (for a list of techniques used to deal with such conflicts see here).
Your specific language can be expressed as the LL($1$) grammar
$$S \to \texttt{id}\ S'$$
$$S' \to A' | F'$$
$$A' \to \texttt{=}\ exp$$
$$F' \to \texttt{(}\ arglist\ \texttt{)}$$
One of the cons with this approach is that your syntax tree won't be as nice as in the original grammar, and might need some post-processing after the parse.

In practice, you do what needs doing to parse the text.
If A and F didn't both start with "id", S would check which is the next token and then match the appropriate rule. In your case here, A starts with id and EQ, while F starts with id and LPAREN. So S just needs to know the next two tokens and can then match the correct rule, without changing the grammar and much of the parser.
Not all grammars can be handled that way. Sometimes Knogger's answer can rescue the sitution in these cases. Needing knowledge of a limited number of tokens but more than two is relatively rare.
